# Auto refresh screens of my friends

Tags: google-drive

Every 5 min I am uploading a file on Google Drive using backup and synchronize option.

Let's say the file name is `stockchart.jpg` image file

Now I am sharing this file with my 25 friends every day. 
Few friends viewing on mobile few may be on a desktop. 
And this image will be open on their screen from 9.15 am till 3.30 pm.

Every 5min I am overwriting stockchart.jpg on Google Drive but as soon as I upload the file it should get an auto-refresh on the screen of my friends.

I don't want them to refresh the screen or view my file every time.

Every 5 mins refreshing manually is an irritating task.

Image size will be Always same since I automated this process with some code.

How can I do it? Please help to suggest me the best solution.

Comment: Pls suggest which platform...it seems u did not understand my post..

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is not the right application to use because you can't force an auto-refresh (from your end only) on other computers.

This could be done in Google Sheets which is able to refresh every hour or every minute. It would require to upload the image somewhere on site and then use **`IMPORTXML`** formula to scrape the image from there into the spreadsheet.

On the other hand, if you are able to influence your friends to install a Chrome extension, there is **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-refresh/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg)** which is able to auto-refresh the page in given intervals:

[image: 0]

Comment: Any one can help me to Google sheet macros..which will replace latest image automatically every 5 min.. Macros will pickup image from Google drive or local folder..hope when macros replace latest image my all friend will get latest image on their screen.

Comment: @ShankarMore If you are still looking for help with macros I suggest you to post a new question.